# Python 2.7 install on Scientific Linux 6 via SCL devtoolset

Tags: yum, python, scientific-linux, scl

I understand Scientific Linux 6 uses Python 2.6.6 for several critical utils, including yum, according to this article [How to install Python 27 on Centos 6](http://toomuchdata.com/2014/02/16/how-to-install-python-on-centos/#comment-12109.)

The simplest and hopefully cleanest install I found is based on Red Hat Software Collection and the devtoolset-3 package which I already installed 
according to [Compiling in Scientific Linux](https://github.com/catsop/python-sopnet/wiki/Compiling-in-Scientific-Linux-6.5)

I stopped at the next step:

```
yum install python27
scl enable python27 bash
```

Could you advise whether it will be 'safe' to proceed further as instructed without an alt-install. Thanks.

Comment: The gihub you link is about the installation of `python-sopnet` not python itself.  Are you trying to install `python-sopnet` or just `python 2.7.12`?

Comment: python 2.7.12. Thanks for raising this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should verify that `python27` is coming from SCL and not elsewhere.

In my case I am using CentOS 6, but the process is the same.

So:

```
$ yum info python27  
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
6 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Available Packages
Name        : python27
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 1.1
Release     : 25.el6
Size        : 5.2 k
Repo        : centos-sclo-rh
Summary     : Package that installs python27
License     : GPLv2+
Description : This is the main package for python27 Software Collection.
```

We can see it comes from `centos-sclo-rh` and so is the right version.

We can install this.  Because it's from SCL it will install into `/opt/rh` and this will *not* impact any other aspect of the OS:

```
$ sudo yum install python27
...
$ ls /opt/rh
python27
```

We can see the default python is still unchanged:

```
$ /usr/bin/python --version
Python 2.6.6
```

Now we need the `scl` command.  This is from the `scl-utils` package, which you may need to install (`yum install scl-utils`).

```
$ scl enable python27 bash
```

This runs a new shell with the path changed:

```
$ scl enable python27 bash
bash-4.1$ echo $PATH
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/etc:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
bash-4.1$ command -v python
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/python
bash-4.1$ python --version
Python 2.7.8
```

So enabling and running SCL does not impact the core OS; it won't break anything you normally run but allows for a newer version of python to be installed in parallel (in `/opt/rh`).

Comment: `/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/python` is a soft link, which ends at `/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/python2.7`.  An alternative too using `scl` to call a new shell is to add a soft link (e.g. `/usr/local/bin/python2.7`) and explicitly state the use of `python2.7` in the scripts that need it.  Hacky, yes, but still explicit enough to not confuse people that will do `which python2.7`.  Good answer btw (+1)

Comment: @Stephen: thanks so much for posting such a detailed answer. I have `slc6-scl` for repo as expected since I fetched SCL/devtoolset-3 from [SL] (https://root.cern.ch/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=18262). Any idea where it will install to in `/opt`?

Comment: If the SCL stuff is built to be compatible with RH, it _should_ be in `/opt/rh` the same as the CentOS version.

Comment: Reporting back: successful install of python 2.7 in `/opt/rh` where `devtoolset-3` took residence. In short, it works for Scientific Linux 6 too. Thanks so much again.